# JavaScript heap out of memory while importing opencv.js and yarn build

Tags: javascript, opencv, yarnpkg

While importing opencv.js version 3.4 in my index.js file and calling function `import cv from opencv.js` I am getting error `FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory`. Increasing heap size by passing parameter `--max-old-space-size=10000` does not seem to work.

Comment: How much free memory do you have?

Comment: around 10 GB out of 16 GB RAM

Comment: `cv = require('opencv.js');` works fine when I have just 5 gigabytes free. Are you perchance running this in a Webpack/bundler environment? If so, you should make sure your bundler doesn't attempt to analyze or transpile the opencv.js module (which is 7.9 MB).

Comment: Currently running into this issue. How do I make sure the bundler doesn't attempt to analyze or transpile the opencv.js module?

Comment: Hi @user142206, I know it's way too late but Have you found a solution for this issue?